# Remove Insertion bar in my js button

Tags: javascript, html

This is my button, he is working pretty good, but he is ugly...:

```js
function MyFunc() {
  var MyDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById("MyBody").appendChild(MyDiv);
  var MyButton = document.createElement("input");
  MyButton.id = "Mybuttonid";
  MyButton.className = "Mybuttonclass";
  MyButton.setAttribute("value", "open");
  MyDiv.appendChild(MyButton);
}
```

```css
#Mybuttonid {
  padding: 2pt;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10pt;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10pt;
  background-color: rgba(59, 59, 59, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body id="MyBody">
  <script>
    MyFunc();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And I want to remove this insertion bar that stays when I click the button

i'll try to put an image....[The Image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKFGQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add the attribute `type="button"`.

```js
function MyFunc() {
  var MyDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.getElementById("MyBody").appendChild(MyDiv);
  var MyButton = document.createElement("input");
  MyButton.id = "Mybuttonid";
  MyButton.className = "Mybuttonclass";
  MyButton.setAttribute("value", "open");
  MyButton.setAttribute("type", "button");// added line
  MyDiv.appendChild(MyButton);
}

MyFunc();
```

```css
#Mybuttonid {
  padding: 2pt;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10pt;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10pt;
  background-color: rgba(59, 59, 59, 1);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body id="MyBody">
</body>
```